# Error installing php extension OAuth by pecl, please help me

Tags: linux, php, configuration, oauth

I'm trying to install the php extension OAuth in my centos 6 linux server. php.net suggests it's super easy. You just run

```
pecl install oauth
```

I tried this, and here is the output in terminal:

---

```
[root@www extensions]# pecl install oauth 
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update 
pecl.php.net" to update
downloading oauth-1.2.2.tgz ...
Starting to download oauth-1.2.2.tgz (45,348 bytes)
.............done: 45,348 bytes
6 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootlyYnpP/oauth-1.2.2
running: /var/tmp/oauth/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
configure: error: Cannot find php-config. Please use --with-php-config=PATH
ERROR: `/var/tmp/oauth/configure' failed
```

Answer (score 3):

There's an error:

```
configure: error: Cannot find php-config.
```

and on the same line, instructions on how to fix it:

```
Please use --with-php-config=PATH
```

Obviously, `PATH` needs to be replaced with the actual path to your `php-config`.

---

If you don't have `php-config` installed, you will have to install that first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer! my php-config in /usr/local/php/bin/php-config. But I do not know how to use --with-php-config=/usr/local/php/bin/php-config, where should I input --with-php-config=/usr/local/php/bin/php-config? which command should I use?

Comment: +1. If PHP is self-compiled and installed in a "non standard" directory then `--with-php-config` must be set to that directory. If PHP is installed from the RPM-package, it just means that the development-package of PHP is not installed - on Centos 6 it's called `php-devel`

Comment: Thanks that did it. But my site cannot open after install oauth:(